# How to terminate an application using the HINSTANCE

Tags: c++, handle, terminate, hinstance

I am spawning an application from c++ with ShellExecute, so I have the HINSTANCE of the app.

How can I close it now using that HINSTANCE? And can I use WaitForSingleObject() to wait for the app to finish?

Comment: Is the spawnee application yours or third party? Typically graceful shutdown is easier when the child app cooperates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an `HINSTANCE` is of very little use in modern versions of Windows -- but what you have isn't really an `HINSTANCE` anyway. The return from `ShellExecute` is really just a value greater than or less than 32, to indicate success or failure respectively.

Fortunately, if you use `ShellExecuteEx`, you can get a process handle for the new process, and you *can* use that to control the process.

The MSDN article that @Remus linked is decent, but (IMO) there's another step that can be useful if the target application is (or might be) a console application. In this case, it usually won't handle a `WM_CLOSE` message. You can, however, inject a DLL into the process, and have that do a clean(ish) shutdown from inside the process (for example, if it calls `exit`, and the target program is written in C, it'll get a chance to flush and close files, run anything registered with `atexit`, etc., before dying).

If that fails, you might want to use `GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent` to send it a control-break.

Then, if all those fail to exit you call `TerminateProcess`.

Comment: I switched to ShellExecuteEx, but my problem now is that .hProcess is always null. I've set fMask to SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS like msdn says I should to get the hProcess, but its always null.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to gracefully shutdown a process. There is an abrupt an non-graceful way by using [`TerminateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but this will prevent the process from running its own cleanup code and may leave stuff 'in-limbo', see [Quick overview of how processes exit on Windows XP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/05/03/2383346.aspx).

For a long time now the common wisdom about 'terminating a process' was to send a WM_CLOSE to the process topmost unowned window(s), in expectation that the application will respond by quitting gracefully. See [How To Terminate an Application "Cleanly" in Win32](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893), and also this mandatory reading on the related subject of finding the right window: [There can be more than one (or zero): Converting a process to a window](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/02/20/7806911.aspx)

Ans you should also read [What can I do with the HINSTANCE returned by the ShellExecute function?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/05/590749.aspx) to understand why the HINSTANCE you have is not trustworthy, not to say useless...